# PCA Matrix Shapes

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

This is a simple, kind of, yes no question.  I am trying to understand PCA, and I am going through the [wikipedia article on PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis).  Something is throwing me off.  I am going through the details section.  Throughout this section we assume that we are using a matrix of data, called `X`:

> Consider a data matrix, X, with zero empirical mean (the empirical
>   (sample) mean of the distribution has been subtracted from the data
>   set), where each of the n rows represents a different repetition of
>   the experiment, and each of the p columns gives a particular kind of
>   datum (say, the results from a particular probe).

A little farther down it explains how we get the principle components decomposition of X as:

```
T=XW
```

quote from wikipedia article:

> where W is a p-by-p matrix whose columns are the eigenvectors of XTX

My question is: is this a mistake?

`X` is an n x p matrix, so it would be impossible to do matrix multiplication if `W` is a p x p matrix.  `W` would have to be p x n.

Am I right, or is `W` always p x p and I am still not getting something?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a n x p matrix multiplied to a p x q matrix is a n x q matrix. n x p * p x p gives a n x p matrix.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ is $n \times p$ and $W$ is  $p  \times p$, so the multiplication $XW$ is fine.